# Sum of timestamps in unix

Tags: text-processing, arithmetic

I need a code to add 2 timestamps of format `HH:MM:SS` in unix, can anybody help?

Unfortunately, I have stored timestamp as varchar in the database, in the format (e.g.)

```
07:53:39
```

Now I want sum of that timestamp which I have stored as a varchar.

I have written the following query to convert varchar into timestamp by removing the colons, now I want sum of this timestamp how I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you should be able to add two timestamps together fairly easily.  Here I'm doing it in SQLite3:

```
sqlite> select time("07:53:39","02:00:10");
09:53:49
```

```
sqlite> create table test ( id integer, ts varchar );
sqlite> insert into test (id,ts) values (1,"07:53:39"), (2,"10:12:01");
sqlite> select * from test;
1|07:53:39
2|10:12:01
sqlite> select time(a.ts, b.ts) from test a, test b where a.id=1 and b.id=2;
18:05:40
```

Both of these examples actually abuses the time zone offset to add a certain amount of time to the given timestamp.